# SharePoint Public Folders

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have been using public folders to hold all email which our staff want to store and access. One big issue is you cannot search Public Folders (sub folders) in any way. One way is to add each sub folder as a favorite, but there are 100's.

We run Office 365 online. So we would be looking to SharePoint online

In our Current Setup we have for example:

Public Folder -> Customer Name A -> Mail

Public Folder -> Customer Name B -> Mail

Public Folder -> Customer Name C -> Mail

My Questions are these.

1. In SharePoint is there an equivalent system to Public Folders and what is it called. I just don't know where to start reading up on this area.
2. In SharePoint, can you have Folders and Sub Folders and Sub Folders and be able to search at any level? Returning relevant results

Answer (score 0):

1 - yes, its called document library and in the library you can have document sets, folders and documents.

2 - yes the sharepoint will search using metadata (keywords) and also the contents of the documents.

You can make these entirely or partially public as you wish